# Custom camera preview issue on sony xperia

Tags: android, android-camera

I have developed a custom camera application, and its working fine on all other devices except on Sony Xperia Neo L.

The problem is that the camera preview which I am getting back from camera is very slow or lagging. I had earlier ran the same code without any error and lag on an older Xperia phone, so i am surprised a bit as why this issue has arose.

The only change that I found in these executions is that the logcat is showing the following warning and some weird things after starting the camera

```
05-24 11:20:57.766: I/CameraService(138): Opening camera 0
05-24 11:20:58.196: E/SEMC Camera HAL(138): Store old settings
05-24 11:20:58.196: E/mm-camera(138): config_proc_CAMERA_SET_PARM_FPS: 30
05-24 11:20:58.196: E/SEMC Camera HAL(138): Store old settings
05-24 11:20:58.196: E/mm-camera(138): config_proc_CAMERA_SET_PARM_FPS: 30
05-24 11:20:58.296: E/mm-camera(138): config_proc_CAMERA_SET_PARM_FPS: 0
05-24 11:20:58.396: E/mm-camera(138): config_proc_CAMERA_SET_PARM_FPS: 30
05-24 11:20:58.486: E/mm-camera(138): config_proc_CAMERA_SET_PARM_FPS: 0
05-24 11:20:58.626: I/AwesomePlayer(138): setDataSource_l('/system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg')
05-24 11:20:58.626: E/CMarlinMediator(123): Error : MarlinMediator Failed to get TrustedTime
05-24 11:20:58.636: I/AwesomePlayer(138): setDataSource_l('/system/media/audio/ui/VideoRecord.ogg')
05-24 11:20:58.646: E/CMarlinMediator(123): Error : MarlinMediator Failed to get TrustedTime
05-24 11:20:58.666: D/CameraService(138): getParameter
05-24 11:20:58.666: W/ServiceManager(138): Permission failure: com.sonyericsson.permission.CAMERA_EXTENDED from uid=10141 pid=11654
```

I tried to Google around with this permission failure issue, but didn't got any solution.

I have already mentioned the required permissions in the manifest file, only the problem is with Neo L. The pre installed camera application in this phone works well,so there is no issue with the hardware I guess. Please somebody help me on this.

Edit:
    After opening the camera i have following code

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new PreviewCallback() {
            public synchronized void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera c) {

                if (mCamera != null) 
                { 
                    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer); 
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes i have mentioned the permissions: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

Comment: @Panky90 if the same code works on other devices not your sony device then i guess you should contact the manufacturer to check if it requires any additional settings or permissions

Comment: @Raghunandan would that be the case? But the same code is working on Xperia LT18i as well.

Comment: I suspect it's your implementation problem. Please post some code on your implementation. Are you using `setPreviewCallback(Camera.PreviewCallback)` ?

Comment: @ChintanRathod In other devices always the "0" camera is opening.

Comment: @NcJie Yes i am using the setPreviewCallback(Camera.PreviewCallback) method. I will update the question with that code for you.

Comment: @ChintanRathod I had checked that post earlier, but i am already using the camera id as "0".

Comment: do you think is there any issue of resolution here? coz i faced that while checking application in micromax a100 and resolution of camera not set well and got error. not like as you post but just telling you.

Comment: @ChintanRathod I don't think there might be an issue with the resolution as I am setting one of the resolutions that is supported by the phone.

Comment: Is your application just to display the frame grabbed from camera without manipulating it? If so, you can remove `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer` to decrease the overhead.

Comment: @NcJie My application is manipulating the grabbed frame data. So i have to use it.